# OpenCV - approxPolyDP not finding rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, polygon

When using opencv's approxPolyDP function on a webcam feed to detect rectangles i sometimes run into an error.

Attached are two images, in both of these the rectangle can be seen, but the approxPolyDP function only sometimes finds a rectangle, other times it just finds a straight line between the two diagonal corners.

Im using the drawContours function to draw directly on the color image, but the approxPolyDP is used on a grayscale image also attached.

The code to generate the poly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size();i++) {
    double epsilon = 0.06*arcLength(contours[i], true);
    approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours[i], epsilon, true);
}
```

Any ideas why im getting the line instead of the rectangle? If more code is needed please ask.

[The result of the function returning the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSeOb.png)

[Grayscale input of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYYcW.png)

[Kind of correct result of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWrXY.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the output of drawContours contains many segments (more than two, I mean, a correct output), I'd try to reduce the epsilon in approxPolyDP, in order to make the Douglas-Peucker algorithm discard less segments.